# connect magento site with other platform site using API and display same quantity in both sites

Tags: api, quantity, multi-vendor

we are working on Magento Marketplace Multi vendor site.

Means Sellers can able to sell the products through our site.

Our sellers are selling the same products in other e-commerce site [not magento - http://www.flipkart.com/ ],

http://builtwith.com/flipkart.com - platform of flipkart site.

sellers using **same sku in both our site and in flipkart**.

what we want to achieve is **display** **"same Quantity" in both sites.**

Suppose if one product sold in flipkart, than quantity will decrease in flipkart.

same quantity should reflect in our site too for that sku.

flipkart provides an **API** for this : https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/FMSAPI.html

Is it possible to display same quantity in both sites using an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible if both sites support webhooks. Magento 2 (and Magento 1) at the moment does not provide such functionality out of the box, but you might implement something custom since you have control over it. I don't know if http://www.flipkart.com/ has webhooks functionality, if not - then you need to modify their code.

On the other hand, if webhooks are not available, you can implement some script which will periodically request current quantity from both systems via web API and then make updates if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable hints, we are using 1.9. is there any online tool we can find whether  webhooks functionality is available or not for flipkart.com....

Comment: Not sure, try to search in their documentation (if available).